# Read data directly from REST Api with Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

Is such a situation even possible ? :

There is an application "XYZ" (in which there is no Kafka) that exposes a REST api. It is a SpringBoot application with which Angular application communicates.

A new application (SpringBoot) is created which wants to use Kafka and needs to fetch data from "XYZ" application. And it wants to do this using Kafka.

The "XYZ" application has an example endpoint `[GET] api/message/all`  which displays all messages.

Is there a way to "connect" Kafka directly to this endpoint and read data from it ? In short, the idea is for Kafka to consume data directly from the EP. Communication between two microservices, where one microservice does not have a kafka.

What suggestions do you have for solving this situation. Because I guess this option is not possible. Is it necessary to add a publisher in application XYZ which will send data to the queue and only then will they be available for consumption by a new application ??

Comment: Did you consider Connect REST interface https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html ?

Comment: Between two calls to `api/message/all`, how would you guarantee there's no duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Getting them via the REST-Interface might not be a very good idea.
Simply put, in the messaging world, message delivery guarantees are a big topic and the standard ways to solve that with Kafka are usually

- Producing messages from your service using the `Producer-API` to a Kafka topic.
- Using `Kafka-Connect` to read from an outbox-table.

Since you most likely have a database already attached to your API-Service, there might arise the problem of dual writes if you choose to produce the messages directly to a topic. What this means, is that writes to a database might fail while it might be successfully written to Kafka/vice-versa. So you can end up with inconsistent states. Depending on your use case this might be a problem or not.

Nevertheless, to overcome that, the `outbox pattern` can come in handy.

Via the outbox pattern, you'd basically write your messages to a table, a so-called outbox-table, and then you'd use Kafka-Connect to poll this table of the database. Kafka Connect is basically a cluster of workers that consume this database table and forward the entries of the table to a Kafka topic. *You might want to look at confluent cloud, they offer a fully managed Kafka-Connect service. Like this you don't have to manage the cluster of workers yourself*. Once you have the messages in a Kafka topic, you can consume them with the standard Kafka `Consumer-API/ Stream-API`.

What you're looking for is a `Source-Connector`.
A source connector for a specific database. E.g. MongoDB

E.g. https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb

For now, most source-connectors produce in an `at-least-once` fashion. This means that the topic you configure the connector to write to might contain a message twice. So make sure that if you need them to be consumed exactly once, you think about deduplicating these messages.